# Print Letter "A" depending on the input size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a program for school, and my homework is to create Letter "A" and the size depends on persons input.

I only worked with loops, `print`, and `input`, so I work with what I have.

I tried the following code:

```
v = eval(input("Enter the size of the Letter: "))
for i in range (v):
    print(" " * ((v/2)-i) + i * '*' + ((v/2)-i))
```

..but I get an error.

Comment: Can you please specify the error you are getting?

Comment: if you're getting `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`, it's because the last two terms of the print statement: `'*' + ((v/2)-i)` is really `str + int` and python's print function can't combine different datatypes -- so you need to convert the `((v/2)-i)` part to a string

Comment: I am getting error something about int as you said but in any way i can not print out a letter "A" with only loop,print or input

Answer (score 0):

Using if statements, my code below seems to work. I am not sure if it is possible without them.

```
v = eval(input("Enter the size of the Letter: "))
for i in range(1, v, 2):
    if i == int(v/2):
        middle = i * '*'
    else:
        middle = '*' + (i-2) * ' ' + '*' if i != 1 else '*'
    print(" " * int((v/2)-(i/2)) + middle + int((v/2)-(i/2)) * " ")
```